# Service worker for Rails app - caching for offline use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, service-worker

My Rails app depends on the application cache (via the Rack-Offline gem) to allow users to 'download' a dynamic form to their mobile browsers so that they can access and fill out the form while they are offline and then submit it when they get back to wifi/network coverage.  Everything is working great, but, of course, app cache is deprecating, seems like hopping over to service worker would be the thing to do.

There is a new gem for service worker (https://github.com/rossta/serviceworker-rails), but the tutorial cuts off when the instructions get to the part about using the cached assets... I am not an experienced enough programmer to know how to proceed without someone holding my hand.

Has anyone encountered any comprehensive resources dealing with adding service worker to a Rails app?  Or perhaps have built something yourselves and would be willing to share your insights?  I think my needs are relatively simple - cache an html doc and a few associated scripts and stylesheets, serve them from the cache if the user is offline on subsequent visits.

Comment: Curious if you found the resources you were looking for. I am about to attempt something similar. I want to administer a survey offline. Here is an article I found that might be helpful. [Your First Progressive Web App on Rails](https://rossta.net/blog/make-your-rails-app-a-progressive-web-app.html)

Comment: @Nathan No, I never really did. I got pulled into some other work and sorta left this issue unresolved (app still works, though). Thanks for the tip on the article - that was published after I was dealing with this issue, so I'll have a look! I did reach out to the developer of the gem and he got back to me, but I didn't follow up any further as I got wrapped up in other stuff...

Comment: You won't be able to render dynamic pages offline (e.g. show.html.erb, index.rhtml) since you have no server-side language possible. You need to generate a static website to make available offline: so only .html, .js, .css, images, pdf, .txt file, etc. But no index.html.erb or index.php

Comment: @pmrotule thanks for the tip!